# Импорт товаров в интернет-магазин на 1С.Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, 1с

Товарищ попросил помочь с сайтом. Есть интернет-магазин на 1С.Битрикс, нужно в него добавлять товары с другого интернет-магазина. Если распарсить инфу с других магазинов я могу, то как ее программно добавлять в 1С.Битрикс? Никогда не сталкивался с этой CMS. Может, у 1С.Битрикс есть какой-то API или можно адекватно добавлять товары сразу напрямую в БД?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день. Вы можете это сделать написав собственный скрипт импорта и используя необходимые для добавления товаров/цен/остатков соответствующие API-функции. Подробнее можете почитать в официальной [документации](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/) по использованию API. Вам нужна информация о классах модуля ["Торговый каталог"](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/classes/index.php).

Также 1С-Битрикс поддерживает импорт торгового каталога из xls и csv файлов.
И вы можете написать собственный [шаблон импорта товаров](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/templates_import.php).
Все что Вам будет нужно это написать свой скрипт парсинга других сайтов и затем обрабатывать полученные данные в 1С-Битрикс. Полученный скрипт лучше всего повесить на агента в 1С-Битрикс, чтобы его работа не тормозила сайт. Или если не нужна периодическая работа - то сделать мастер для ручного запуска по необходимости.